# How can a class access its super class variables even there are not protected?

Tags: java, package, visibility, private

Given the sample code:

```
package com.tt;
class Bigger 
{
     int a = 5;
}

class lower extends Bigger 
{
    void m1() {
        int z = super.a;
    }
}
```

Why the lower class can access the varaibles of Bigger class enven they are not protected?
I 'm refering to thisvisibility matrix

Access Modifiers:

```
         Same Class  Same Package   Subclass   Other packages
public          Y       Y              Y             Y               
protected       Y       Y              Y             N
Default         Y       Y              N             N
private         Y       N              N             N
```

Comment: And why do you think they won't be accessed given that table?

Answer (score 4):

The derived class `lower` can access the field `a` on the super type `Bigger` because the field 'a' has its scope set to the default scope, package private.  In this scenario the inheritance relationship plays no part in the access to the field.

When a scope is not provided for a field declaration the access level of the field defaults to package private.  This is the current case for the field `a` on class `Bigger`.  This grants classes within the same package, such as `lower` access to the field.

Within your table the field falls under this access level:

```
         Same Class  Same Package   Subclass   Other packages
public          Y       Y              Y             Y               
protected       Y       Y              Y             N
Default         Y       Y <-- Here     N             N
private         Y       N              N             N
```

Answer (score 0):

u can access the super class variables if they are not in protected mode  by using ***super***
keyword

```
Class A{
int a;
}
Class B extends A
{
void apply(int c)
{
super.a=c;
}
}
```

this will set the value of a in class A
 and vice versa u can access the variables.....